# Firebase - Angularfire2 subscribe wait for response to return value

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, angular5

I have a problem with the asynchronous operations of Angularfire2. I want to create a new resource in my Firebase database but first I want to check if exists a resource with the same name and return a message to the front-end.

The problem is that I can't return the message into the `subscribe` method. VS throws this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2355  (TS) A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
```

This is my function code:

```
createInstance(instanceName: string): string {
      this.databaseService.getList('/Events/' + instanceName).subscribe(
          result => {
              var message;
              if (result.length === 0)
              {
                  this.databaseService.update('/Events/' + instanceName + '/Configuration', myObject);
                  message = "Instance created";
              }
              else
              {
                  message = "Instance already exists";
              }
              return message;
          });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are running is asynchronous, hence you `subscribe` to the response in order to get informed when the operation has completed.

Your function however, runs synchronously, so it gets executed and returns before the database fetches the data, that happens later.

So the error you're getting is because your function is not actually returning anything, but it's declared as returning a `string`, which you only get later in time.

One solution is to declare you function as an `Observable`, like the database service you're using, and consume it asynchronously.

For example:

```js
// extra import you'll need
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

createInstance(instanceName: string): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.databaseService.getList('/Events/' + instanceName).subscribe(result => {
            if (result.length === 0) {
                this.databaseService.update('/Events/' + instanceName + '/Configuration', myObject);
                observer.next('Instance created');
            } else {
                observer.next('Instance already exists');
            }
            observer.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

And you consume it like this:

```js
createInstance('test').subscribe(message => {
    // here you go
});
```